# Installing Ubuntu, It cannot find the root file?

Tags: system-installation

When I am installing Ubuntu 12.04, it takes me to a screen where I can partition my harddrive, so let's say `sda1` is my windows, `sda2` is something else and `sda3` is something else.

Whenever i click install on one of them with any boot loader option it gives me it says, it cannot find the root system file,

Answer (score 0):

Windows only works with NTFS file system,when i try to to install 12.04 LTS,I faced the same problem.
Go back and choose **Ubuntu to install in a new partition** i.e) it creates automatically creates a new partition
                          ***or***
Create a  new partition of your choice, greater than minimum requirement size and specify the type of file system and specify your root folder i.e).given in a toolbar with option (/,/root,/home and etc....like that).choose any one from that,and try to install from that partition